# HAML for PHP SilverStripe

Tags: php, haml, silverstripe

Is there any chance to use HAML with [SilverStripe](http://silverstripe.org/) framework? I found [PHamlP](http://code.google.com/p/phamlp/wiki/InstallationAndUsage) but don't know how to implement it to the framework. Thx for your tips...

Answer (score 1):

May be posible, but I doubt it's worth the effort: http://silverstripe.org/customising-the-cms/show/15215